# Processing NaN and Infiniti in computing in Java

Tags: java

There is a method for the construction of a power.

```
public static double raisedToPower(double a, double b) {
    return Math.pow(a, b);
}
```

The evaluation method can return the value of NaN, and Infinity, which can break the program at the point of call.

In my mind I have to handle this in a method (if result is Infinity or NaN -  return key, which can be treated outside the method). That is the question, what can l return as the key, or is there another way to handle this situation?

```
public static double raisedToPower(double a, double b) {
    double res = Math.pow(a, b);
    if (Double.isNaN(res) || Double.isInfinite(res)) {
        return key;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: That is the question. Key is a value that the one calling this method will use to identify that something has gone wrong.

Comment: If you're going to test for `key` anyway, why can't `key` be `NaN`?

Comment: @harold hence my answer :)

Comment: Why not throw an Exception here as this is invalid input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're sure that some value can never otherwise be returned (e.g. -1), you should probably go with whatever `Math.pow()` returns and then test it with [`Double.isFinite()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isFinite-double-) to make sure it's valid.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways here.

1. Throwing exception, e.g. `IllegalArgumentException` with a message like *"undefined/impossible result for these parameters"*.
2. Returning a specific value, e.g. `-1`. Old-fashioned C way, but often used for math operations.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use custom Exceptions and combine them with argument checking.

```
public static double raisedToPower(double a, double b) throws NanException, InfinityException {
    double res = Math.pow(a, b);
    if(Double.isNaN(res))
        throw new NanException();

    if(Double.isInfinity(res))
        throw new InfinityException();

    return res;
}
```

Then, where you need it:

```
    double foo;
    try {
        foo = raisedToPower(1.0, 0.0);
    }
    catch(InfinityException ie) {
        //handle IE
    }
    catch(NanException ne) {
        //handle NE
    }
```

Comment: you're using Exceptions for control flow, although it seems like an easy solution a proper if/else would a better way to handle logic